# opencl image with mirroring at border

Tags: opencl

Can I set up an opencl image so that coordinate access past the boundary
of the image will return the mirror image?

For example, if image is of dimensions width by height, then

```
read_floati(width, 0)
```

will return

```
read_floati(width-2,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Read section 6.11.13 of the OpenCL specification. OpenCL images are read using (for example) `read_imagef` function and that function takes a *sampler* which can be set up for mirroring using `CLK_ADDRESS_MIRRORED_REPEAT`.